# Find and Replace Value in Table From DLookup Multiple Criteria VBA

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, filtered-lookup, dlookup

I'm start to do programming in Access, and I really need help!!

My objective is to create a module that is run in "tbCustoProjeto" table and rewrite the field "Valor HH" values based on Dlookup. I found some solution (by azurous) who I think will solve this, but when I run the code, is returned

> "object-required-error".

```
Sub redefineHH()
Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim value As Variant
Dim HHTotal As Double
Set HHTotal = DLookup("[CustoTotalNivel]", "tbNivelNome2", "nUsuario='" & tbCustoProjeto!NumUsuario & "'" & "AND Numeric<=" & tbCustoProjeto!DataNumero)

'initated recordset obejct
objRecordset.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
Call objRecordset.Open("tbCustoProjeto", , , adLockBatchOptimistic)
'find the target record
While objRecordset.EOF = False
'If objRecordset.Fields.Item(13).value > 0 Then
objRecordset.Fields.Item(13).value = HHTotal
objRecordset.UpdateBatch
'exit loop
'objRecordset.MoveLast
objRecordset.MoveNext
'End If
Wend
MsgBox ("Pesquisa Finalizada")
End Sub
```

Print of tbCustoProjeto

[image]

Print of tbNivelNome2

[image]

Please, someone can tell me where is the error? I don't know what to do.

Comment: Saving aggregate data is usually a bad design. Calculate the total when it is needed.

Comment: I don't see any records in tbNivelNome2 that will meet Numeric criteria in DLookup().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot reference a table directly like that for dynamic parameter. DLookup should pull dynamic criteria from recordset and within loop. Don't use apostrophe delimiters for number type field parameter.

Remove unnecessary concatenation.

```
Sub redefineHH()
Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
objRecordset.Open "tbCustoProjeto", CurrentProject.Connection, , adLockBatchOptimistic
While objRecordset.EOF = False
    objRecordset.Fields.Item(13) = DLookup("[CustoTotalNivel]", "tbNivelNome2", _
        "nUsuario=" & objRecordset!NumUsuario & " AND Numeric <=" & objRecordset!DataNumero)
    objRecordset.UpdateBatch
    objRecordset.MoveNext
Wend
MsgBox ("Pesquisa Finalizada")
End Sub
```

Comment: June7, thank you very much for your help. I can filter perfectly the field with: `objRecordset.Fields.Item(13) = DLookup("[CustoTotalNivel]", "tbNivelNome2", _ Numeric <= objRecordset!DataNumero)`....... and I can filter with: `objRecordset.Fields.Item(13) = DLookup("[CustoTotalNivel]", "tbNivelNome2", _ "nUsuario=" & objRecordset!NumUsuario)`............., but not with the both. Do you know why? (type-mismatch-error)

Comment: Since nUsuario is a number type field, remove apostrophe delimiters. I should have noticed that and removed them. Edited answer.